# Concrete example of behaviour of two AsyncTasks launched at same time before Donut

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have implemented the class "trick" about differentiate between `execute()` and `executeOnExecutor()` but I ask myself how my app would behave in my concrete scenario.

In my activity I have 2 AsyncTask. One of them is an animation that is **always** running on background. Never stop until activity closes. I had to do so, with an AsyncTask, because I could not make work with Android `Animation` class. It is an infinite background scroll.

In the other hand I have an AsyncTask that downloads a file from Internet.

Due to before Donut AsyncTasks run serial, how my app would work considering the first task is always running on background and the second could stop when finish download?

If they execute serial, as the first task is always running, it would let the second execute some time? I think the app would never execute the second.

Would it work so? How I could solve? Would I forced to do in only one?

Comment: AsyncTask only runs serially *now* (ICS and later). It only briefly ran concurrently in Honeycomb. Regardless, AsyncTask is specifically *not* designed to run continuously. Use a thread or other concurrency mechanism.

Comment: But I would manage the UI (I'm moving a bitmap as a scroll) from a Thread? I though it only can do it from an AsyncTask. Using threads, can I create as many want?

Comment: You'd have to send messages from the background thread to the UI thread, or set a repeating runnable on the UI thread. Google a bit. It's way too much to explain in a comment (and too broad for an answer).

Comment: Thanks for all. I didn't know that I could make several Threads so I was forced to do all with AsyncTasks.